# Slow Stoch Crossover in Oversold/Overbought where crossover is by a certain amount

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, stochastic

I am struggling to figure out how to get customise my strategy for a slow stoch crossover. This is what I currently have which defines that when there is a crossover in overbought or oversold it triggers the position. I want it to go further so when "k" crosses over/under "d" by a value of +/-2 respectively. (this seems to improve the accruacy). Any idea how this can be coded in pine?

```
//Stochastic Inputs
length = input.int(14, minval=1)
OverBought = input(80)
OverSold = input(20)
smoothK = 3
smoothD = 3
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, length), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
//Rule to define crossover /crossunder
co = ta.crossover(k,d)
cu = ta.crossunder(k,d)

if (not na(k) and not na(d))
    //code to define if k is in overbought zone and k crossover d and enter a long trade
    if (co and k < OverSold and is_uptrend)
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long")
    //code to define if k is in oversold zone and k crossunder d and enters a short trade
    if (cu and k > OverBought and is_downtrend)
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.short, comment="Long")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for crossover/crossunder and compare the value of `k` and `d`.

```
co = ta.crossover(k,d)
cu = ta.crossunder(k,d)

co_valid = co and ((k - d) > 2)
cu_valid = cu and ((d - k) > 2)
```